# Simplest way to do parallel replicate

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am fond of the `parallel` package in R and how easy and intuitive it is to do parallel versions of `apply`, `sapply`, etc.

Is there a similar parallel function for `replicate`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can just use the parallel versions of `lapply` or `sapply`, instead of saying to replicate this expression `n` times you do the apply on `1:n` and instead of giving an expression, you wrap that expression in a function that ignores the argument sent to it.

possibly something like:

```
#create cluster
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)  
# get library support needed to run the code
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(MASS))
# put objects in place that might be needed for the code
myData <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
clusterExport(cl,c("myData"))
# Set a different seed on each member of the cluster (just in case)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl)
#... then parallel replicate...
parSapply(cl, 1:10000, function(i,...) { x <- rnorm(10); mean(x)/sd(x) } )
#stop the cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

as the parallel equivalent of:

```
replicate(10000, {x <- rnorm(10); mean(x)/sd(x) } )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing when I read that replicate was just a wrapper for sapply.

Comment: @D1X, Did you try the code?  When I ran it as it was, I saw 10,000 unique values, no duplicates.  But I tested on windows, which only spawns, not forks.  If you use forking instead of spawning to create the cluster and a seed is set in the parent, then you might get duplicates.  I added a call above to explicitly set the random seeds on each child process, just in case (and made some other minor changes to make the code runnable as is).

Comment: Yes, this is fixed with the seed setting (And yes I was running this in Linux). Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The **[future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply)** package provides a plug-in replacement to `replicate()` that runs in parallel and uses statistical sound parallel random number generation out of the box:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession, workers = 4)

y <- future_replicate(100, mean(rexp(10)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `clusterEvalQ` as a model, I think I would implement a parallel `replicate` as:

```
parReplicate <- function(cl, n, expr, simplify=TRUE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
  parSapply(cl, integer(n), function(i, ex) eval(ex, envir=.GlobalEnv),
            substitute(expr), simplify=simplify, USE.NAMES=USE.NAMES)
```

The arguments `simplify` and `USE.NAMES` are compatible with `sapply` rather than `replicate`, but they make it a better wrapper around `parSapply` in my opinion.

Here's an example derived from the `replicate` man page:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
hist(parReplicate(cl, 100, mean(rexp(10))))
```