# R - parallelizing ldply and replicate functions

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have tried for quite some time to parallelize this code, to no avail. I either get errors or nothing works. Anyone have any ideas?

```
cal_Ops <- function(n, dtm, ratio = 0.1) {
  print(n)
  selVect <- sample(nrow(dtm), nrow(dtm) * ratio)
  holdout <- dtm[selVect,]
  training <- dtm[-selVect,]
  topModel <- LDA(training, n, control = list(estimate.alpha = FALSE))
  return(c(n, perplexity(topModel, holdout), as.numeric(logLik(topModel))))
}

require(plyr)

replication <- 1000

sequ <-seq(5,100,5)

perplex <- ldply(sequ, function(x, dtm) {
   t(replicate(replication, cal_Ops(x, dtm))) } , dtm = DTM_to_use)
```

It takes a LONG time to run as is. Thank you, in advance.

I've tried using this example as a parallel version of replicate - but, I had many errors: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19281611/8598566

Comment: What machine are you on? Windows? Linux/Mac?

Comment: I'm doing some testing on Windows, but ultimately this will run on a small HPC cluster running CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not reproducible, e.g. `DTM_to_use` is not defined, making it hard to help other than "the-following-should-work" suggestion:

The `plyr::ldply(x)` function takes argument `.parallel = TRUE`, which will process `x` in chunks distributed to whatever number of workers you have.  This uses the [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach) framework internally for parallel processing.  With that you can use any of the "do"-packages.  Here is an example using future backends:

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()

## Utilize all cores available to this R session
plan(multisession)

replication <- 1000
sequ <-seq(from = 5, to = 100, by = 5)
perplex <- plyr::ldply(sequ, function(x) {
   t(replicate(replication, c(a = x, b = sqrt(x))))
}, .parallel = TRUE)

str(perplex)
'data.frame':   20000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ b: num  2.24 2.24 2.24 2.24 2.24 ...
```

Since you mentioned that HPC is your target: If you have an ad-hoc cluster without a job scheduler but where you can SSH into each node, then you can use:

```
plan(cluster, workers = c("node1", "node2", "node2", "node3"))
```

to run one core each on `node1` and `node3` and two cores on `node2`.  If you do have a real job scheduler, say SGE, then you can use:

```
library("future.batchtools")
plan(batchtools_sge)
```

and the each element in `sequ` will be processed as an individual job on the queue (which effectively corresponds to having an infinite number of workers).  If you want to chunk it up, you can limit the number of workers (= jobs), e.g.

```
plan(batchtools_sge, workers = 200)
```

Your script will look identical regardless of backend used.

EDIT 2023-05-30: The (virtual) future backend `multiprocess` is defunct in favor of `multisession` and `multicore`. Updated example to use `plan(multisession)` now.